I can't install Laravel on my desktop. I get this as part of the error message:- https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem
Using the command of laravel new {name of project} in my Visual Code Ide terminal will not install on my desktop computer.
I get this message:-
Failed to download laravel/framework from dist: curl error 60 while downloading https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/framework/zipball/16b31ab0e1dad5cb2ed6dcc1818c02f02fc48453: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Now trying to download from source
Failed to download phpunit/phpunit from dist: curl error 60 while downloading https://api.github.com/repos/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/zipball/4dc07a589a68f8f2d5132ac0849146d122e08347: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Now trying to download from source
I have researched it on Google the best I can but have come up with no answer as to what to try to correct the problem
